# MagickBlobErrorException: no such file or directory

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines, testcase

When i run the testcase c# application from windows(local machine) it works fine. But when run from azure pipeline getting below exception. Anyone faced like this error? Please help me on this.

i used code:

MagickImage sourceImage = new MagickImage("../../../Images/OutputImages/output-SlightSkew.jpg");

Got error:

Error Message:
ImageMagick.MagickBlobErrorException : UnableToOpenBlob '../../../Images/OutputImages/output-SlightSkew.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537
Stack Trace:
at ImageMagick.NativeInstance.CheckException(IntPtr exception, IntPtr result)
at ImageMagick.MagickImage.NativeMagickImage.ReadFile(IMagickSettings`1 settings) at ImageMagick.MagickImage.Read(String fileName, IMagickReadSettings`1 readSettings, Boolean ping)
at ImageMagick.MagickImage.Read(String fileName, IMagickReadSettings`1 readSettings)
at ImageMagick.MagickImage.Read(String fileName)
at ImageMagick.MagickImage..ctor(String fileName)

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, the error is most likely due to the wrong file path.

In Azure DevOps pipeline, your source code files are in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory).

You can check if there is a `output-SlightSkew.jpg` file in `../../../Images/OutputImages/` in your repository.

If the answer is no, change your path to the correct path.

If the answer is yes, try to replace your path to a specific path, for example `{folder A}/{folder B}/Images/OutputImages/output-SlightSkew.jpg`.